# Why is GeoDjango not able to query geom column from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango

I'm using postgis and (geo)Django to build a web app. I've imported a shapefile into postGIS and used inspectdb to create the model. models.py looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class MySpatialModel(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    col2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    col... = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=20935, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'myspatialmodel'
```

If I query this model using `MySpatialModel.objects.values_list('col1')` there is no problem.

If I try `MySpatialModel.objects.all()` I get the following error:

```
WindowsError at /whatEverLink/

exception: access violation reading 0x03A10000
```

I have the spatial table on a different schema to public but have tried moving it across the public schema (and ensuring that Django is accessing the right schemas) but the problem persists.

The exception location is here:

```
django\contrib\gis\geos\prototypes\threadsafe.py in __call__, line 56
```

Comment: Have you come across [this old blog post](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/django-1-2-and-geodjango-on-windows/) where a GEOS reinstallation fixed a similar problem?

Comment: @metasequoia Thanks. Definitely a path problem somewhere. I just tried the same code on a linux setup and it's working fine. I'll update the original when I've got to the bottom of it. As a "workaround" I set up geoserver so things are functioning regardless.